# Getting danda in Devanagari in IAST

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, indic

I am trying to get the danda symbol that is in Devanagari in IAST. My code is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\san}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Shobhika}
\newfontfamily{\rom}[Mapping=itrans-iast]{Noto Serif}
\newcommand{\sd}{{\san|}}

\begin{document}
{\san
namaste|
}\\
{\rom 
namaste{\sd}
}\\
{\rom 
namaste|
}
\end{document}
```

When I use `\sd` which I declared in the preamble, I can get the danda in the \rom environment. Is there  a way I can directly get the danda in the `\rom` environment without using the `\sd` by using some declaration in the preamble.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the character `|` to be an active character (so that it gets treated like a macro) and give it the same definition as your `\sd`, by adding these two lines:

```
\catcode`|=\active
\let|=\sd
```

Modifying your example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\san}[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Shobhika}
\newfontfamily{\rom}[Mapping=itrans-iast]{Noto Serif}
\newcommand{\sd}{{\san|}}

\begin{document}
{\san
namaste|
}

{\rom 
namaste{\sd}
}

{\rom 
namaste| (before)
}

\catcode`|=\active
\let|=\sd

{\rom 
namaste| (after)
}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output for example]

In practice you'd probably want to put those lines at the top of the file; just make sure it's after `\sd` has been defined (and after any `|` character in your file that's being used for any purpose other than as a Devanagari danda).